# Ubuntu Version for Toshiba Satellite Model No.: C850-I0012

Tags: system-installation

Which Ubuntu version does Toshiba Satellite Model No.: C850-I0012 support? Please provide me with the links to download drivers if any are required.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is powerful enough to support the standard version of Ubuntu 64 bit.

Test a liveDVD or liveUSB before installing.